# Mechanize: Search all Forms

Tags: ruby, mechanize

It appears that both of these give me access to the first FORM element in a document:

```
page.form
page.forms.first
```

How can I search for a particular checkbox like

```
page.form.checkbox_with(:name=>"yep")
```

if I don't know which FORM it is inside?

Comment: You need to find all check boxes in all forms or all forms with check boxes present?  If first use something like `page.forms.collect {|form| form.checkbox_with(:name=>"yep") }.compact` if second - use like `page.forms.select {|form| form.checkbox_with(:name=>"yep") }`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you want all the forms with that checkbox, or only the first one?

For the first one, do

```
form = page.forms.detect { |f| f.checkbox_with(:name => "yep" ) }
```

For all, do

```
forms = page.forms.select { |f| f.checkbox_with(:name => "yep" ) }
```